# Elasticsearch nested query for auto-complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

I want to make sure I'm thinking about this in the right way.  I'm trying to use Elasticsearch for an auto-complete for nested items.  I have a list, and a list has many items.  I want to use ES to return matching item names, weighing them more strongly if they're present in the current list by passing both the list name, and item name to search in Elasticsearch.

I could in theory simply index Items separately and search them that way, but I'd rather search them through the List document so that I can control relevancy.

I can't figure out how to return an item that nearly matches what's put in.  Here's my setup... (Rails using Elasticsearch-Rails and Elasticsearch-Model)

The Index Mappings:

```
  settings :index => { :number_of_shards => 1  } do
    mapping :dynamic => 'false' do
      indexes :private, :type => 'boolean'
      indexes :name, :type => 'string'
      indexes :slug, :type => 'string'
      indexes :bookmarks_count , :type => 'integer'
      indexes :item_names, :type => 'string'
      indexes :up_count, :type => 'integer'
      indexes :permalink, :type => 'string'
      indexes :sub_text, :type => 'string'
      indexes :title_text, :type => 'string'
      indexes :creator_name, :type => 'string'
      indexes :creator_avatar, :type => 'string'
      indexes :cover_image, :type => 'string'
      indexes :items, :type => "nested" do
        indexes :name
        indexes :description
        indexes :image_url
        indexes :link
      end
    end
  end
```

The JSON:

```
  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    as_json(:include => [:items, :tags],
            :methods => [:permalink, :sub_text, :title_text, :icon_url, :item_names, :creator_name, :creator_avatar, :cover_image]
            )
  end
```

Here's the method I call for the search:

```
  def item_typeahead_search(list_name, search_query, page = 1, per = 5)
     wildcarded_query = "*#{search_query}*"
     ::List.search(item_typeahead_querystring(list_name, wildcarded_query)).per(per).page(page)
   end

  def item_typeahead_querystring(list_name, query_string)
    {
       :query => {
         :bool => {
           :should => [
             { :match => { :name => list_name }},
             {
               :nested => {
                 :path => "items",
                 :score_mode => "max", 
                 :query => {
                   :bool => {
                     :must => [
                       { :match => { "items.name" => query_string }}
                     ]
             }}}}
           ]
     }}}
  end
```

Here's a sample query...

```
results = List.item_typeahead_search("try me", "crazy glue")
```

Here are the results...

```
=> #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Result:0x007fb8f25c5208
 @result=
  {"_index"=>"lists",
   "_type"=>"list",
   "_id"=>"54504855f29a589a2700003b",
   "_score"=>8.652843,
   "_source"=>
    {"_id"=>"54504855f29a589a2700003b",
     "bookmarks_count"=>0,
     "carousel"=>nil,
     "cid"=>"5j18j8aor",
     "content_source_name"=>nil,
     "content_source_url"=>nil,
     "created_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:52:21Z",
     "description"=>nil,
     "down_count"=>0,
     "down_voters"=>[],
     "intralist_id"=>"545057f7692a270e03000266",
     "items"=>
      [{"_id"=>"545048d5f29a589a27000044",
        "created_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "description"=>nil,
        "down_count"=>0,
        "down_voters"=>[],
        "image_small_url"=>nil,
        "image_thumb_url"=>nil,
        "image_url"=>nil,
        "link"=>nil,
        "name"=>"a swiss army knife",
        "order"=>nil,
        "picture"=>nil,
        "up_count"=>0,
        "up_voters"=>[],
        "updated_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "vote_count"=>0},
       {"_id"=>"545048d5f29a589a27000045",
        "created_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "description"=>nil,
        "down_count"=>0,
        "down_voters"=>[],
        "image_small_url"=>nil,
        "image_thumb_url"=>nil,
        "image_url"=>nil,
        "link"=>nil,
        "name"=>"duct tape",
        "order"=>nil,
        "picture"=>nil,
        "up_count"=>0,
        "up_voters"=>[],
        "updated_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "vote_count"=>0},
       {"_id"=>"545048d5f29a589a27000046",
        "created_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "description"=>nil,
        "down_count"=>0,
        "down_voters"=>[],
        "image_small_url"=>nil,
        "image_thumb_url"=>nil,
        "image_url"=>nil,
        "link"=>nil,
        "name"=>"Crazy glue",
        "order"=>nil,
        "picture"=>nil,
        "up_count"=>0,
        "up_voters"=>[],
        "updated_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "vote_count"=>0},
       {"_id"=>"545048d5f29a589a27000047",
        "created_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "description"=>nil,
        "down_count"=>0,
        "down_voters"=>[],
        "image_small_url"=>nil,
        "image_thumb_url"=>nil,
        "image_url"=>nil,
        "link"=>nil,
        "name"=>"a nut",
        "order"=>nil,
        "picture"=>nil,
        "up_count"=>0,
        "up_voters"=>[],
        "updated_at"=>"2014-10-29T01:54:29Z",
        "vote_count"=>0}],
     "name"=>"try me",
     "parent_list_creator"=>nil,
     "parent_list_id"=>nil,
     "private"=>false,
     "promoted"=>false,
     "slug"=>"things-for-fixing-anything",
     "up_count"=>0,
     "up_voters"=>[],
     "updated_at"=>"2014-10-29T02:59:03Z",
     "user_id"=>"543809c4b64c402d6a000003",
     "vote_count"=>0,
     "permalink"=>"/lists/things-for-fixing-anything",
     "sub_text"=>"List - created by: CreepyTimes",
     "title_text"=>"try me",
     "icon_url"=>"",
     "item_names"=>"a swiss army knife duct tape Crazy glue a nut",
     "creator_name"=>"CreepyTimes",
     "creator_avatar"=>"https://blahblah.com/uploads/profile/image/543809c4b64c402d6a000004/thumb__old_",
     "cover_image"=>nil,
     "tags"=>[]}}>
```

So, I see "crazy glue" as an item in the list, but it's one of many - not exactly something I can use out of the box here for Auto-complete purposes when someone starts typing an Item name

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do using nested queries, filters or something?  Relatively new to Elasticsearch, so I could use some help on the end solution.  If I'm not thinking about this the right way and should simply index Items, I can do that too, but just curious if there's a way to make this work!

EDIT - this is the query going to Elasticsearch:

```
  #<Elasticsearch::Model::Searching::SearchRequest:0x007fc555032218
   @definition=
    {:index=>"lists",
     :type=>"list",
     :body=>
      {:query=>
        {:bool=>
          {:should=>
            [{:match=>{:name=>"try me"}},
             {:nested=>{:path=>"items", :score_mode=>"max", :query=>{:bool=>{:must=>[{:match=>{"items.name"=>"*crazy glue*"}}]}}}}]}}},
     :size=>5,
     :from=>0},
   @klass=[PROXY] List,
   @options={}>>
```

Comment: Can you look at the log and show us the query sent to ES ? (You should have to enable log in ES::Client)

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm I added the query as an edit to the original post.  Let me know if this helps and thank you for your response!